# In react, will change in props in parent result in a corresponding updation in the child?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

The official documentation of react ( https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html ) says that an update in props results in the child being updated, but it does not happen in my code. Am I missing something?

I created a parent component (Y) and a child component (X). The parent passes currentTime to the child as props. Even though after the props change in the parent after 3 seconds (due to setTimeout), the value in the h2 tag in the child does not change.

I found on the official page of react though ( https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html ) that "An update can be caused by changes to props or state." (I'm attaching a screenshot as well of the text on the official site below) Moreover I found that there that "These methods are called when a component is being re-rendered:"

```
componentWillReceiveProps()
shouldComponentUpdate()
componentWillUpdate()
render()
componentDidUpdate()
```

But in my case the change in props does not cause the value in h2 tag in the child to change. The official documentation says that an update in props results in the child being updated, but it does not happen in my code. Am I missing something?

I've pasted my code here for reference.

```
const Y = () => {

    let currentTime="09:00";
    setTimeout(()=> {
            currentTime = "10:00:"
        }, 3000);

    return (
        <X time={currentTime}/>
    );
};


class X extends Component {
    time = "11:00";

    render = () => {
        return (
            <h2>{this.props.time}</h2>
        );
    };
}
```

Screenshot:
https://prnt.sc/i8kvaw

**Update:
The comment from Shubham Khatri "The props for the child will only change if the parent re-renders", really helped me understand. :)**

Comment: props are immutable within the component, use state to achieve what you want here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the props value currentTime is changed in component Y, it not re-rendered again and hence the child props don't update. If you store the currentTime in the parent state then setting the state of Y component using setState , it triggers a re-render of the component and hence new props are received by the child component X

```
class Y extends Component {

    state = {
        currentTime: "9:00 AM"
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({currentTime: "10:00"}
        }, 3000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
             <X time={currentTime}/>
        );
    }

};


class X extends Component {

    render = () => {
        return (
            <h2>{this.props.time}</h2>
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This I understand. And this should work if I implement it this way. 
By implementing it the above way I'm rerendering the child, as the render method of the parent would be called again.
My question though is that it is written in the documentation that "An update can be caused by changes to props or state". But why is this not happening. I'm changing the props, am I not?

Comment: @BhuvanMishram yes a update is caused by changes in props or state but for that to happen the component which possesses the state needs to re-render. The props for the child will only change it the parent re-renders

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout in parent component is just changing the value of currentTime variable. The render function in parent function is not getting re-rendered so that it updates the child.

You need to set state in parent component for currentTime.

```
this.state = {
  currentTime:"09:00"
}
```

and now you can do

```
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ currentTime: "10:00" }
    }, 3000);
}
```

that will make parent re-render and child will get updated with new prop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This I understand. And this should work if I implement it this way. By implementing it the above way I'm rerendering the child, as the render method of the parent would be called again. My question though is that it is written in the documentation that "An update can be caused by changes to props or state". But why is this not happening. I'm changing the props, am I not?

Comment: You are changing the local variable that is declared inside the functional component - yes. But it (the function) is not getting invoked again. It has returned already before the setTimeout has updated value. React does not apply watchers to the props. Also, one thing to note is that as soon as component is called and ran, the variable being declared is garbage collected.